# Change Select statement in query 

Tags: sql-server-2008, null

I have a table (result of a stored procedure from someone else), and it retuns a table `##tableT` in the form

```
1      2    3    4    5     6
----------------------------------------------
467    116  480  477  491   697
NULL   19   481  113  488   466
123    4354 477  466  55    480
NULL   NULL NULL 527  83    629
45     34   NULL  5   483   483
```

As you can see it has NULLS, and most important the name of the columns are numbers, so when I do

```
SELECT coalesce(1, -1) as att1, coalesce(2, -1) as att2,....,coalesce(6, -1) as att6 FROM [dbm].[dbo].[##tableT];
```

I get:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Instead of:

```
1      2    3    4    5     6
----------------------------------------------
467    116  480  477  491   697
-1     19   481  113  488   466
123    4354 477  466  55    480
-1     -1   -1   527  83    629
45     34   -1   5   483    483
```

Comment: for gawd's sake, don't name your columns with just integers!!

Comment: well, I did not, is the output from someone else stored proc

Comment: yeah, What would be a polite way?

Comment: You're asking an Aussie who accused you of offending a deity with your column names for advice on courtesy?  :-P

Comment: Well, yeah....Kind of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT ISNULL([1], -1) as att1, ISNULL([2], -1) as att2,....,ISNULL([6], -1) as att6 FROM [dbm].[dbo].[##tableT];
```

Answer (score 0):

and as a variant

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN [1] IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE [1] END,
CASE WHEN [2] IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE [2] END,
...
FROM [dbm].[dbo].[##tableT];
```

Comment: wichone would be faster if the table has 1000 columns for example

Comment: faster ? to type ? to exec ? ISNULL is builtin so on first exec it would be faster, if executed often as prepared queries they should be pretty close with ISNULL being a little bit faster...

Comment: Both operationa are the same, as I can remember.